# Phonegap/Cordova App device detection isn't working on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad

I'm a young developer who's school project went viral amongst my school and then was turned into an app. I'm using Phonegap as I'm most advanced in  web languages. I decided to cater for all devices, but originally built it for iPhone layout. To make it look good on iPad, I used Cordova device detection to implement my changes (I know this is bad) like this:

```
//Checks what device is being used
var deviceType = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))  == "iPad" ? "iPad" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i))  == "iPhone" ? "iPhone" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) == "Android" ? "Android" : (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) == "BlackBerry" ? "BlackBerry" : "null";
//Width & Height for Tannock Image
var width = 178.5;
var height = 270;
//If device is iPad
if(deviceType == "iPad"){ 
$('#teaImg').css('height', '540px');    
$('#teaImg').css('width', '357px');    
$('#text1').css('margin-left', '38%');
$('#text1').css("font-size", '35px');    
width = 357;
height = 270;    
}
```

This shocking code was working absolutely fine when I directly fed it to my iPad through Xcode, but when I downloaded it from the app store, this was no longer working and so instead of looking like I wanted it to, it didn't apply any of these changes.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.s The app is called Tannock Tapper, I know it's buggy, I'm a one man team and school takes priority.

Comment: dude, is it your code ? then you forget to end if condition with "}" . please update proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my code according to device orinted as following:

I Set you code in my format for your use.

```
var isAndroid = navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i) ? true : false;
var isIPhone = navigator.userAgent.match(/iphone/i) ? true : false;
var isIPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad/i) ? true : false;
var isBlackberry = (navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)) ? true : false; 

var width = 178.5;
var height = 270;

//If device is iPad
if(isIPad){ 
    $('#teaImg').css('height', '540px');    
    $('#teaImg').css('width', '357px');    
    $('#text1').css('margin-left', '38%');
    $('#text1').css("font-size", '35px');    
    width = 357;
    height = 270;    
}

// If device is android
if(isAndroid){
// android related code
}

if(isBlackberry){
// Black berry related code.
}
```

i also have same code in my app and i am using this code from last 3 years in my app which is already in app store.

Ping me if looks confusing.

Comment: Hey, thanks, hopefully that will work, but I have no way to test it but release an update for the app, how should I test it, as when I fed it from Xcode to my iPad, it gave me a different result, thus I won't be able to see if it works.

Comment: from xcode in your ipad what is result, any error or what?

Comment: No, not with your version or mine, I take the xcodeproj file from platforms/ios. I'm right in that?

Comment: yes just double click on that default it will open in **xcode**

Comment: Yes I have done that, but when it is simulated on my iPad, there is no error, but when I download it from the app store, there is an error

Comment: you can check log in safari also when you run app in ipad.

Comment: Ok how do I do that?

Comment: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/ please go through

Comment: I think I just found it. There was an error to do with a js animation where I did: width: width + px, instead of  width: width + "px", or width: width. Which one would be better to use?

Comment: $("#someElement").css({ 'height': setHeight + "px" }); will be good one..